# using Ansible to create GCP storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, google-cloud-storage

I am trying my hands with `ansible` to handle `GCP resources` . Initially I am trying to create a `GCP storage bucket` using `ansible` . For this I installed `ansible` in `GCP CLoud Shell` using below command . Also created a `service account` and generated JSON based key file .

```
   sudo apt-get install ansible
```

Also installed gcloud module using below command

```
   sudo pip3 install google.cloud
```

Now I am trying to create a `Storage bucket` using below `YAML` file

```
- name: create a bucket
  tasks:
  - name: Storage bucket
    google.cloud.gcp_storage_bucket:
      name: ansible-storage-module
      project: test_project
      auth_kind: serviceaccount
      service_account_file: "/tmp/auth.json"
      state: present
```

But it is failing with below error when I ran with `ansible-playbook`

```
  ansible-playbook ansible.yaml

 ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

 The error appears to have been in '/home/project/ansible/ansible.yaml': line 4, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
```

The offending line appears to be:

```
- name: Storage bucket
  ^ here
```

Comment: You are attempting to a module from the `google.cloud` ansible collection. It doesn't look like you've installed it. The command would be something like `ansible-galaxy collection install google.cloud`.

Comment: If you see my original description , it is already executed using sudo pip3 install google.cloud

Comment: I installed ansible again using pip and it worked . With apt-get it was not working

Comment: If you see my original comment, I didn't say anything about `pip install`, which installs Python modules. I suggested using `ansible-galaxy collection install`, which installs Ansible collections.

Comment: Initially I tried with `ansible-galaxy collection install` but somehow it was failing after which I tried `pip install`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this by installing both `Ansible` and `google-auth` using `pip`.

```
 pip install ansible
 pip install requests google-auth
```

and little modification on `playbook` to make it work

```
 - name: create a bucket
   hosts: localhost
   tasks:
   - name: Storage bucket
     google.cloud.gcp_storage_bucket:
       name: ansible-storage-module
       project: adminproject-272208
       auth_kind: serviceaccount
       service_account_file: "/home/project/ansible/project.json"
       state: present
```

`gsutil` shows bucket was created

```
     $ gsutil ls
     gs://ansible-storage-module/
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using a python virtual env make sure the `ansible_python_interpreter` is been declared properly.

Here is a full example with the entire setup with a Python venv:

```
python3.9 -m venv ~/py39
source ~/py39/bin/activate
pip install ansible
pip install google-auth
```

Then create a proper ansible directory tree like:

```
plays/ansible.cfg
plays/inventory
plays/main.yml
```

Where `plays/ansible.cfg` have:

```
[defaults]
inventory = inventory
interpreter_python = ~/py39/bin/python
```

The `plays/inventory` have:

```
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

The `plays/main.yml`:

```yaml
---
- name: "Creating a Bucket on GCP"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: "Creating the Bucket"
      google.cloud.gcp_storage_bucket:
        name: "The_bucket_name"
        project: "The_project_name"
        auth_kind: "serviceaccount"
        service_account_file: "/your/service/account/file.json"
        state: present
      register: bucket
```

Finally run in:

```
cd plays
ansible-playbook main.yml
```